# Multitouch not working in cocos2D for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, multi-touch

I am quite familiar with cocos2D (been working with it for over 1 year) and I encountered a problem with my `multitouch` game - the `multitouch`.

What I have:
`[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]`  in my delegate.
A `playscene` that does NOT implement touches.
Many objects (of my own, inherits CCLayer) that are added to playscene.
These objects implement touches and are delegates of the targeted protocol.
`[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];`

The very same architecture is used in the touches test from cocos2D and it's working.
The only difference is that they use `CCSprite` instead of `CCLayer` as the parent class for the objects.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Still looking for a solution for this?  What happens when you touch the screen with your implementation.  Do you get any kind of response in your touch callbacks (begin/moved/finished)?

Comment: Well, you will never guess! Of course I knew XCode is not the best IDE in the world and that sometimes you should clean the project and rebuild...but I never thought to do a new project and import everything in there. That was the problem!!! How f**ked up...I thought I only had to code... After that , everything worked ok.

Comment: Yeh that can happen sometimes.  Good to hear everything is working now.  You should add that as answer to your question to close it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you will never guess! Of course I knew XCode is not the best IDE in the world and that sometimes you should clean the project and rebuild...but I never thought to do a new project and import everything in there. That was the problem!!! How f**ked up...I thought I only had to code... After that , everything worked ok.

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

in app delegate:

```
[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]
```

then in you game you see the touches like this:

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
- (void)ccTouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
```

With this I sold my problem I hope it helps